# Outlier cutoff in R

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

I am trying to cut off the outliers of a variable of a dataframe however it does not perform as expected:

```
outlier_cutoff1 <- quantile(myd$nov, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(myd$nov)
index_outlier1 <- which(myd$nov > outlier_cutoff1)
mydnov <- myd[-index_outlier1, ]
```

this code does not give error but does not change the outlier values.

Comment: It is almost never a valid approach to remove outliers simply because they are in the tails of a distribution.  It is the nature of most data to have tails, and removing them falsifies the results.  Outliers typically need be removed only if there is a known reason that measurement errors occurred so that we should not trust their validity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `which` here.

Looking at your code, I think you can remove the "outliers" with the below:

```
outlier_cutoff1 <- quantile(myd$nov, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(myd$nov)
index_outlier1 <- (myd$nov > outlier_cutoff1)
mydnov <- myd[-index_outlier1, ]
```

Here's a reproducible example that verifiably works (with a vector).

```
set.seed(123)
nov <- rnorm(500)

outlier_cutoff1 <- quantile(nov, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(nov)
  #This is 2.574977 
index_outlier1 <- nov > outlier_cutoff1
  #This returns a logical vector inticating when each value is greater than 2.574977 

mydnov <- nov[-index_outlier1]

length(nov)  #500

length(mydnov)  #499, one was removed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know that it works for you.I couldn't test fully without a reproducible example.

```
myd_wo_outliers <- subset(myd, myd$nov > (Q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & myd$nov < (Q[2]+1.5*iqr))
```

Check out this [page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/01/how-to-remove-outliers-in-r/) for more details.